# Facebook Tab App unable to get user_location

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

My facebook tab application cannot get user_location from normal users. When I add this user to the test users, app gets the location. Here is my js code;

```
       FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                var test_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?';
                test_url += 'app_id=myappid';
                test_url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent('link_to_my_app');
                window.top.location = test_url;
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                var oauth_url = 'http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/';
                oauth_url += '?client_id=myappid';
                oauth_url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent('link_to_my_app');
                oauth_url += '&scope=email,user_location';
                window.top.location = oauth_url;
            } else {
            }
        });
```

I cannot get the possible reason of this. How can I solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `user_location` permission cannot be used by Users without a role in your App before it has been reviewed by Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login